# will push notifications with Production-SSL certificate work when I'm still testing my app? How can I know it will work?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My push notifications are working fine with the sandbox model. I just verified that the production ssl certificate is working both with direct SSL-connection and with AWS SNS. However, my device is still producing the same push token as it produced for the sandbox, and this token is not working for production-level push notifications (rejected as invalid token by Apple server). Is it supposed to work? How can I make sure push notifications are working/will work for users who download the app from the app store?

Comment: If you signed your build with proper production certificates, all will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a provisioning profile for "Ad Hoc" distribution, using your production certificate.  Sign your app with that and install.  Make sure your SSL connection to APNS knows which certificate to use, depending on whether client is production or dev.